# Redis bitnami Helm Chart FAILED statefulset.yaml nil pointer evaluating interface {}.BasePath

Tags: kubernetes, redis, bitnami, kubernetes-statefulset, base-path

I am very new to Kubernetes and cant seem to fix this issue.
I am trying to install bitnami/redis helm chart but receive the following error:

**Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml:40:44: executing "redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml" at <$.Template.BasePath>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.BasePath**

This is the statefulset.yaml section 40:44
[statefulset.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyquq.png)

what am I supposed to change to fix this? sorry if this is super easy but I'm only new.

Steps.

1. $ helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
2. $ helm install redis bitnami/redis

I used default values files.
I have minikube installed on my Linux centOS8 VM.

Comment: Please add some more details for other to replicate the issue. What command did you use to install the chart? Are you using the default values file? Where is your K8s cluster?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue, using `helm install redis bitnami/redis` with the default values everything is up and running in minikube.
You can run `helm template redis bitnami/redis --debug` in order to render the templates without deploying any k8s resources. In the same way, the `--debug` flag will increase the verbosity of the output

Comment: I was half way through a udemi course aswell which I have a redis instance deployed. Would having one already used make any difference?

Comment: **This is the output after runnign debug**

Error: template: redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml:40:44: executing "redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml" at <$.Template.BasePath>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.BasePath
helm.go:88: [debug] template: redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml:40:44: executing "redis/templates/replicas/statefulset.yaml" at <$.Template.BasePath>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.BasePath

Comment: i was running a rc version of helm.. thanks everyone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.